# Single table design for no-SQL - Use case with no design pattern

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling, dynamodb-queries

I'm building a model in DynamoDB following the principles of single table design by Rick Houlihan.
The process shows how to model a 1:M and M:M relationship by using composite keys in primary key and sort keys.

For exemple:
Let's say we have a model for training classes.
We have STUDENTS and CLASSES which are basic entities. And we have a REGISTRATION entity which connect a student to a class. So far no issue and the table to hold this data is below.

If I want to get all the classes that student2 is registered I will query by PK=Student#002 and SK begins with 'Class#'.

```
PartitionKey        SortKey          EntityType
---------------     ----------       ----------
Student#001         Student#001      STUDENT              
Student#002         Student#002      STUDENT
Student#003         Student#003      STUDENT
Class#001           Class#001        CLASS
Class#002           Class#002        CLASS
Class#003           Class#003        CLASS
Student#001         Class#001        REGISTRATION
Student#002         Class#001        REGISTRATION
Student#002         Class#002        REGISTRATION
Student#003         Class#002        REGISTRATION
```

Now consider that in my model I have an status attribute on classes which could be OPEN,CLOSED,CANCELED. The table will be like below.

Similar to previous query I want to get all the classes that student2 is registered with status OPEN.
Repeating the query with PK=Student#002 and SK begins with 'Class#' is not enough.

```
PartitionKey        SortKey          EntityType     Status
---------------     ----------       ----------     ----------
Student#001         Student#001      STUDENT              
Student#002         Student#002      STUDENT
Student#003         Student#003      STUDENT
Class#001           Class#001        CLASS          OPEN
Class#002           Class#002        CLASS          CANCELLED
Class#003           Class#003        CLASS          OPEN
Student#001         Class#001        REGISTRATION   
Student#002         Class#001        REGISTRATION
Student#002         Class#002        REGISTRATION
Student#003         Class#002        REGISTRATION
```

One solution could be prefixing the status in the sort key like below.
However this does not appear a good solution as the status is a transitory information.
Anytime a class changes the status all the registration records need to be updated to keep consistency. Not to mention the cost of this operation considering that a class can have 10k students registered.

```
PartitionKey        SortKey               EntityType     Status
---------------     ----------            ----------     ----------
Student#001         Student#001           STUDENT              
Student#002         Student#002           STUDENT
Student#003         Student#003           STUDENT
Class#001           Class#001             CLASS          OPEN
Class#002           Class#002             CLASS          CANCELLED
Class#003           Class#003             CLASS          OPEN
Student#001         OPEN#Class#001        REGISTRATION   
Student#002         OPEN#Class#001        REGISTRATION
Student#002         CANCELLED#Class#002   REGISTRATION
Student#003         CANCELLED#Class#002   REGISTRATION
```

Is there any way to solve this scenario properly in noSQL ?

Comment: Can you clarify what your access patterns are? There are numerous options, but they vary largely based on how you really need to access the data and how much the data changes. Do classes change status frequently? Do students have a large number of classes? Do you often query the classes for a student? How often do you need to find the students in cancelled classes as opposed to just students in a single class?

Comment: The datamodel is larger than this and for all the rest I managed to handle all the access patterns. Just this part that I'm struggling. A common access pattern after login is: give me all the classes that I'm registered which status is OPEN. The class status will change often and will have other status (closed, on hold)

Comment: How often the class status would change? What are the actual number of total students, total classes, average opened class per student?  How many times a day a student would request to view registered open classes?

Comment: Class status starts with OPEN, change to IN PROGRESS while classes is in progress (it can remain in progress for hours, days or weeks depending on duration of class) and finally change to CLOSED. It can chance to CANCELLED if class is cancelled or ON HOLD if temporary suspended for registration. Students would start increasing and expected to be around 100k on 1st year. Classes would be initially around 500. Every time the user logins we shall present what he is registered. We will show the ones that still pending to start and those that is already in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Single table design with DynamoDB is cool but it is limited in some cases.

If I have 10k students, and I need to query all the OPEN registered classes for a student, and classes can be opened and canceled, then I would probably have Elasticsearch synced with the dynamodb table like:

- DynamoDB - Dynamodb Stream - Lambda - Elasticsearch
- refer https://github.com/vladhoncharenko/aws-dynamodb-to-elasticsearch/blob/master/scripts/dynamodb-to-es.py for the lambda syncing DDB to ES

I would be able to query all the open classes for the student2.

Comment: Adding ElasticSearch as solution will increase the complexity.
If I would go this way then I rather prefer to give up on noSQL and use relational database which can solve this problem with a simple query:

select * 
from   registration reg, classes cl 
where  reg.student = 'student#001' 
and    reg.classid = cl.classid 
and    cl.status = 'OPEN'

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two options here.

1. Get the list of classes for a student (this would include all classes regardless of status) and then do a `batchGet` to get each of the classes, to filter the list down by status in your code. As long as the number of classes a single student is enrolled in isn't large this is a reasonable approach. Even if the number gets large you can add [DAX](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/dax/) to reduce the number of requests to the table and increase the performance.
2. Take the approach you mentioned in the last part; update each of the student records. The easiest way to accomplish this would be to use a [Stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) to capture the change and update the records as needed. This makes the process asynchronous. If your process to change the status of a class is already asynchronous then you can do the work there. You mentioned the cost of this, but I don't think the cost is going to be that high. Even in a case where there are 10K students in a class the update would cost $.0025, or 1/4 of a penny if the records are small enough (this is not accounting for the cost of a lambda running on a stream trigger, just the update cost to the table). You can do quite a few updates at that cost before really seeing a cost issue, and compared to the cost of alternatives it will still be a lot cheaper.

There are other options. As another person suggested, you can add ElasticSearch. You could also push the data to S3 and use Athena. I assume you want to stay in DynamoDB, in which case the above two options are the best I can think of (perhaps someone else has another idea).

Answer (score 0):

I found more problematic scenarios like the one described in this post, so I realized that no-SQL wasn't the right DB choice for this project.
I have changed to Aurora RDS.